# Camel - Trying to marshall parameters with JIBX and send it to CXF-CAMEL endpoint

Tags: cxf, apache-camel, jibx

Basiaclly I've got the XML-d object to send, thanks to JIBX, I've got the WSDL endpoint. I just want to get the thing to that endpoint. it's proving extremely difficult for me.

I would like to use POJO mode because it looks much simpelr than the other modes doesn't involve messing with SOAP-Headers, and so on

POJO mode seems to invoke JAXB by default but I'd like to use JIBX - since the projects I'm interfacing with are already JIBX annotated and

I would like to either swap the POJO automatic JAXB-ing with my JIBX or just let me do the marshalling myself (which I can do successfully) and pass on my xml message

```
from( "A" )
  .marshall().jibx() // works fine, and gives byte[] of marshalled object in In.body
  .process() {
      exchange.getIn().setHeader( CxfConstants.OPERATION_NAME, OPERATION);    
   }
   .to("cxf://SERVICE"
     + "?serviceClass=SERVICE_CLASS"
     + "&wsdlURL=SERVICE?wsdl"
     + "&dataFormat=POJO" );
```

It then tries to invoke Jaxb on the messagebody and dies.

I've tried wrapping byte[] as a String, and wrapping in a List
and sending with dataformat=MESSAGE
but I can't seem to get what I'm trying to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

user1958722,

I would recommend taking a look at some of the examples on the JiBX web site and in my blog at [blog.tourgeek.com](http://blog.tourgeek.com)

JiBX has a dataconnector that is included with CXF. This means that all you have to do is specify the jibx dataconnector in your spring bean.xml file and JiBX automatically does the marshaling/unmarshaling.

Athough CXF is a great tool for SOAP servers, I've found it is a bit difficult to use for SOAP clients. You can save yourself a bunch of time by using the JiBX client library. It's very lightweight, because it uses the javax.xml.ws.soap package to package your message in a SOAP container.

I would suggest reading my post on [creating a SOAP client](http://blog.tourgeek.com/2012/11/opentravel-web-services-client-test.html) and taking a look at some of the [sample client code in our repository](https://github.com/jibx/schema-library/blob/master/org.opentravel/_2012A/opentravel-ws/opentravel-hotel-ws-test-client/src/main/java/org/jibx/schema/org/opentravel/_2012A/hotel/ws/test/client/HotelClientTest.java).

The [JiBX schema library](http://jibx.sourceforge.net/schema-library/index.html) has some great [web service client](http://jibx.sourceforge.net/schema-library/client.html) and [server examples](http://jibx.sourceforge.net/schema-library/service.html).

If you are dealing with a public message set, please consider donating your binding to the JiBX schema library.

I hope this helps!

Don

Comment: Mm, Spring, my company are really eager to avoid using Spring wherever possible... 

It seems frustrating I've got the connection set up to the SOAP, I've got the XML-message I just can't seem to figure out how to persuade CXF to put it in.

I'll look through the examples you posted. thanks